# What could "cert 4/52" mean in a clinical record?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviations, medical

What could "cert" mean in these clinical record extracts?

> Work stressful - cert 1/52.
>
> Sent him in to Homerton. Cert 4/52 from 12th March, bus driver.

Comment: Too localised, IMHO.

Comment: The [Health IT stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it) is -really- close to going to beta. Visit and commit!

Comment: I always like it when stack exchange sites are advertised in other stack exchange sites. It's like a big community

Comment: @Thursagen: I was planning to wait for it, but realised that this question is about English and medicine. It would probably be off-topic on HIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but this may mean that the doctor gave the individuals a sick note to pass on to their employers, certifying that the individuals were ill or injured and so unable to work for one week (1/52) or four weeks (4/52).

Comment: That sounds reasonable. The full second record begins with "Wants sick note. Out of hospital two weeks ago."